# Is there any Google Chrome extension that adds search sights like Findbar Tweak extension for Firefox?

Tags: chrome, web-browser, firefox, search, text-search

I am searching for an alternative to "[Findbar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/)" extension that is available on Firefox. I need something similar that runs on Google Chrome.

Mainly, I'm only looking for a feature that allows me to see those "animated circular sights" when searching for a word on a page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Please check the image below to see what I mean by those focus circular "sights".

[image]

Is there any extension for Google Chrome that can do a similar thing?

Comment: The goal is to make the first hit more visible, right? I guess the circle moves to the next its when you click the down arrow button? Are the colours on the scrollbar on the right also a requirement for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, they are not a requirement. I just need the search hits to be clearer. Any kind of motion like circular sights would work in my case.

Comment: This similar question - [Software to help display the "find in page" search](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34948/software-to-help-display-the-find-in-page-search) may be useful? It doesn't do the "circle" but it does make the finding more obvious