# Software to help display the "find in page" search

Tags: chrome

In a web browser we can type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to bring up find box, type in a word and if that word exists on the page it will be highlighted. The page will often scroll (jump) to the location of the selected word

Some times when I search for a word on a web page, I can't see what is highlighted in Chrome. For example if you visit

http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to bring up find and type in `mu` as a find, it shows 3 matches, but I can't see/find them on the page.

In this case, it could be there is a fault with the page/find etc or it could be the highlighting isn't clear! I'm looking for a plugin which when I cycled through each "found word", the highlighting was greatly exaggerated!

I have no opinion on how it should be exaggerated, but as an example a large arrow on the screen appears pointing to the highlighted word which then fades away within a second would make it obvious! This example of the arrow is not criteria, just an example of what I mean by exaggerated!!

Comment: On Firefox, I use [Findbar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/) – which has a nice way to achieve what you want (look for the circle [here](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/116/116848.png?modified=1455331568), which starts big and finally "crushes" on the search term). Not sure if something similar exists for Chrome, as I don't use Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, at least I can do some research though :)

Answer (score 2):

After @Izzy kindly provided a Firefox alternative, which led me to a page which lead me to another page etc, I eventually found something

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-find-for-google-chr/dejblhmebonldngnmeidliaifgiagcjj?hl=en

As you type, the paragraph in question pops up and the screen jumps to location. I would have rather it be a little bit more over the top, but at least I can see what I need to see!

It doesn't appear to work in PDF files which open in web pages!

[image]